# Keeping properties in an Intersection - Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a set of points and I need to classify them according to which polygon they belong. The natural way of doing this is creating the intersections between all points and each polygon. The points have properties I want to keep and the intersection function requires me to have the polygon on the left side and I lose the properties of the input of the right side. How should I go about this? If I use the points on the left side it doesn't work.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/f7b34e63c5e9ad70f96e1ad91620d48a

I want an output that I can download as a .csv with each point, it's characteristics, and an indicator of the polygon they belong.

Code:

```
var p1 = ee.Feature(p1, {id: 'id1'});
var p2 = ee.Feature(p2, {id: 'id2'});
var p3 = ee.Feature(p3, {id: 'id3'});
var p4 = ee.Feature(p4, {id: 'id4'});

var points=ee.FeatureCollection([p1,p2,p3,p4]);
print(points,' points');

var cc1 = poly1.intersection(points, ee.ErrorMargin(1));
var cc2 = poly2.intersection(points, ee.ErrorMargin(1));

Map.addLayer(cc1,{},'cc1');
Map.addLayer(cc2,{},'cc2');

var ccs=ee.FeatureCollection([cc1,cc2]);
print(ccs,'ccs');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's best practice to (i) construct a feature collection of the points; (ii) construct a feature collection of the polygons you have; then (iii) map over both collections to calculate the intersection for every single point; finally, (iv) add the properties to the existing properties of the feature and filter out the ones which did not intersect. Then export the feature collection as csv:

```
// Map over the feature collection of points so we 
// can inspect every single elements intersection and property
var ccs = points.map(function(feat){
  feat = ee.Feature(feat);
  var point = feat.geometry();
  // now map over the polygons
  var mappedPolys = polygons.map(function(poly){
    var intersects = poly.intersects(point, ee.ErrorMargin(1));
    // check if the point intersected with the polygon
    var property = ee.String(ee.Algorithms.If(intersects, poly.get('system:index'), 'FALSE'));
    // set a property to each individual feature
    return feat.set('belongsTo',  ee.String('poly').cat(property))
                .set('pointID', ee.String('id').cat(ee.String(feat.get('system:index'))));
  });
  // return the point with the polygon they intersect with or a property called 'polyFALSE'
  return mappedPolys;
})
  // Flatten the collection of collections and filter out the 'polyFALSE' properties
  .flatten().filter(ee.Filter.neq('belongsTo', 'polyFALSE'));
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/b710430dd57ba50c6a2419e6c72b1422)

Comment: Thank you Kuik. This can get messy if there many polygons. Is there a way to make this more general, so that it is applicable to a large number of polygons? Each polygon would have an ID and the resulting table should have a variable called "belongs to" and the values would correspond to the polygons IDs.

Comment: I edited the answer. See the new link that this would also work for many more polygons/points. And is uses the system property index so you don't have to set id's yourself. If you have already named those points/polygons, then use the name of that property instead of 'system:index'.